# Expanding variables in an ffmpeg command

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to pass codecs to ffmpeg via variables in a bash script, such as

```
VIDEO='libvpx-vp9'
AUDIO='libopus'

ffmpeg -i name.ext \
-c:v "$VIDEO" \
-c:a "$AUDIO" \
name.webm
```

But if I try to pass any options for the codecs, such as

```
AUDIO='libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k'
```

It throws this error:

```
Unknown encoder 'libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k'
```

How do I pass codecs + their options to ffmpeg?

Comment: just remove the double quotes. the whole command should be `ffmpeg -i name.ext -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k name.webm`

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't have guessed that... I can't seem to upvote anywhere, unfortunately.

Comment: When storing complex (multi-word) options, it's best to use arrays instead of plain variables (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash)). For example, `audio=(libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k)` and `ffmpeg ... "${audio[@]}" ...`. Oh, and I also recommend lower or mixed-case variable names, 'cause there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those weird things can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, since the command should be:

```
 ffmpeg -i name.ext -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k name.webm
```

The double quotes should be removed:

```
VIDEO='libvpx-vp9'
AUDIO='libopus -ac 1 -b:a 32k'

ffmpeg -i name.ext \
-c:v $VIDEO \
-c:a $AUDIO \
name.webm
```